# Typesafe config: include "application" doesn't work

Tags: java, scala, typesafe-config

I use typesafe config and try to override some properties in `application.conf` from jar.

I have `application.conf` inside my jar:

```
title: "test-inside" 
sub-title: "sub-test-inside"
```

and `application-test.conf` outside my jar:

```
include "application"
title: "test-outside"
```

I try to use both parameters inside my program.

I launch my jar with the next command:

```
java -Dconfig.file=application-test.conf -jar scala-spark-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: merge of system
> properties,application-test.conf: 1: No configuration setting found
> for key 'sub-title'

typesafe config doesn't use properties from inside `application.conf` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have to set ".\" before external application.conf file name.

> java -Dconfig.file=.\application-test.conf -jar
> scala-spark-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar